# Why does eb cli crash when initializing multi environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

So I was running `eb init --modules modA modB` and at the Application name step it crashes every time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/bin/eb", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 150, in main
    app.run()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 57, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 64, in do_command
    self.initialize_multiple_directories()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 412, in initialize_multiple_directories
    default_env=default_env)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 470, in create_app
    io.log_info('Creating application: ' + app_name)
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

So why is it crashing???

Answer (score 3):

Lo!  There is a bug in the initialize.py file.  It is trying to use a Tuple as a String.  Apply this patch and you're good to go.

```
398c398
<                     self.app_name = self.get_app_name()[0]
---
>                     self.app_name = self.get_app_name()
```

PS - I can't seem to find a maintainer for the `eb cli` tool anywhere.  Maybe they watch Stack Overflow?  Sure would be nice if it was public like the aws cli tool.